# Nest Developer - How to use virtual devices without affecting real devices?

Tags: nest-api

So I signed up for a developer account, with the same email address as my home Nest account.

Now, if I add a virtual device via the Nest Developer Chrome Extension, it shows up via web, in-app etc.

Do I need to create another developer account so that I can have a sandbox which doesn't interfere with my real-world devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice would be to create a separate development account so your virtual devices do not affect the behavior of a real household. Because accounts are free, you can use common techniques like + signs (me+test1@example.com => me@example.com for most email providers) to setup accounts for all sorts of interesting test scenarios.

Then, when you have your code functional, you can pair with your main account an become your first beta tester.